# Getting "Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineVersionCompiler.cmake" with cmake in linux

Tags: linux, cmake, cmake-modules

I'm getting **Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineVersionCompiler.cmake** after installing cmake via script from website. What am I missing and where/what commands to run to fix this issue.

install cmd:

```
sudo ./cmake.sh --prefix=/usr/local/ --exclude-subdir
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(Hello Version 1.0)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ../src/main.cpp)
```

Version: cmake version 3.16.6 (I also tried the latest version 3.17.2 too)

OS: Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside CMake commands all options have **case-sensitive** names, which are usually *upper-case*. So, it is incorrectly to write `Version` instead of `VERSION`. Correct:

```
project(Hello VERSION 1.0)
```

See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/project.html) for `project` command.

Comment: Yup, making VERSION all upper case fixed it. If only the error message just pointed to that line.

Comment: @Mr.UNOwen: See my answer about that.

Answer (score 0):

@Tsyvarev is correct, of course - it's `Version` used instead of `VERSION`.

I've reported this over at Kitware's issue tracker:

- [Improving error messages in this case](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23768)
- [Detection of this kind of errors](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23769)

Feel free to chime in on that page. Hopefully they'll address this at some point (they're often responsive).